# LibGDX Polygon Mask

Tags: libgdx

Is there a way in LibGDX to create a polygon shaped mask? I know how to do a mask with squares and circles but not a polygon. The below code works and renders a mask correctly using a rectangle.

```
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_LESS);
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
        Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);

        // Renders the rectangle
        shapes.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shapes.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        shapes.rect(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, 200f, 200);
        shapes.end();

        batch.begin();
        Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_EQUAL);
        bg.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
        Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

This code below however does not work and simply renders a black screen.

```
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_LESS);
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
        Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);

        // This should be the polygon being rendered as a mask here
        polyBatch.begin();
        polygonSprite.draw(polyBatch);
        polyBatch.end();

        batch.begin();
        Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_EQUAL);
        bg.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
        Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

This code below however renders the polygon just fine and uses the same coordinates as the last example.

```
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // This polygon uses the same coordinates as the last example
        // however it now displays the polygon.
        polyBatch.begin();
        polygonSprite.draw(polyBatch);
        polyBatch.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `batch.begin();` in the third paragraph downwards so that it doesn't enclose the `Gdx.gl` functions, like that:

```
    //batch.begin();
    //from here

    Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_EQUAL);

    //to here
    batch.begin();

    bg.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately it didn't work. I even tried line by line and mixing different lines together and putting them before the batch.begin() method but nothing worked.